# Design pattern name: Is it a factory?

Tags: java, design-patterns, naming-conventions, factory-pattern, thread-local

The following class shows something similar to a real use case. It returns always the same instance for the same thread.

```
public class LookingForName {

    private static final ThreadLocal<Something> threadLocal = 
        new ThreadLocal<Something>(){
            @Override
            protected Something initialValue() {
                return getSomethingSpecial(); // not relevant
            }
        };

    /**
     * @return always the same instance of "Something" for the current thread.
     */
    public static Something getInstance() {
        return threadLocal.get();
    }

}
```

How would you call it? Is it a "factory"? A "value holder"? "ThreadLocalStore"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some simply called it the [ThreadLocal Pattern](http://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/ThreadLocal%20Pattern). Another known name is [Thread-local Storage (TLS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-Specific_Storage).

Comment: I will go with `ThreadLocalSomething` since it describes pretty good what is going on.

Answer (score 4):

Not a factory. looks like a singleton. The idea of the factory is to CREATE objects dirrived on a based class.

Answer (score 0):

`getInstance()` is most definitely a factory method.

Someone might have compe up with a cool name for the entire per-thread-pseudo-singleton, but since it's too rare a case to be widely relevant, there is no value in having it. "Per-thread singleton" sounds like the best option to me.

Comment: I was tempted to downvote this question... But it's technically correct!